# Kivy: Set text attribute inside Screen class

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing a Kivy project where my code will dynamically set the `text` property within a `Screen` class. Below is a MRE that recreates the problem, but my real code is much more complicated.

When I first wrote it, I tried something like `self.ids.my_label.text = 'This no worky'` but  that threw an error:

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I did a `print(self.ids)` and it is empty. Based on some other SO posts (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132728/kivy-attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-getattr)) I added the line `s = self.root.get_screen('screen_one')` but that also throws an error:

> AttributeError: 'ScreenOne' object has no attribute 'root'

I'm assuming the problem is that I'm calling the `ids` within the screen class, whereas every example I am finding is doing it from some other spot. I *sort of* get that calling `self.root` doesn't work because the `ids` doesn't live within the root, but every combo I could think of also doesn't work. I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132728/kivy-attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-getattr), but either I didn't implement it right or it isn't my problem.
What's the solution?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        s = self.root.get_screen('screen_one') 
        s.ids.my_label.text = 'This no worky'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass
    
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenMgr(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MultiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenMgr()
 
sample_app = MultiApp()
sample_app.run()
```

And multi.kv:

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

<MyScreenMgr>:
    transition: NoTransition()
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
    ScreenThree:

<ScreenOne>:
    name:'screen_one'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: my_label 
        Button:
            text: "Go to Screen 2"
            background_color : 0, 0, 1, 1
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
  
<ScreenTwo>:
    name:'screen_two'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Go to Screen 3"
            background_color : 1, 1, 0, 1
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
 
<ScreenThree>:
    name:'screen_three'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Go to Screen 1"
            background_color : 1, 0, 1, 1
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ids` of a widget are not set until after `__init__()` is executed. So the solution is to delay using the `ids`. Here is a modified version of your `ScreenOne` class that does this:

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_text)

    def set_text(self, dt):
        self.ids.my_label.text = 'This worky'
```